# Can a Java ManagedBean method return null?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, navigation, managed-bean

I have always returned `null` when I wanted the user to return to the **same** page. For example, if the user requests to Edit Groups, but he doesn't have access to this, I usually return `null` and print some access denied message. If the user is allowed, I just return the name of the next page, like "Edit".

For example,

```
@ManagedBean(name = "groupController")
@SessionScoped
public class GroupController {

    public String prepareEdit() {
        if (userIsAllowed()) {
            return "Edit";
        } else {
            JsfUtil.addAccessDeniedMessage("Access denied.");
            return null; // return to the same page
        }
    }

    private boolean userIsAllowed() {
        return false; // for testing purpose
    }
}
```

When I return `null`, the same page is returned to the user. So far, so good. But the problem is that after 2 requests I always get a `NullPointerException` like this:

> WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406:
>   Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl$4.invokeContextCallback(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:289)
>           at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:1253)
>           at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:672)
>           at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:1262)
>           at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:672)
>           at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl.restoreView(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:284)
>           at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.restoreView(StateManagerImpl.java:177)
>           at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(ViewHandlingStrategy.java:131)
>           at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:430)
>           at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.restoreView(MultiViewHandler.java:143)
>           at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:199)
>           at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>           at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:110)
>           at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
>           at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:233)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Does anybody know if is correct to return `null` to get the same page? I didn't find any specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning `null` is perfectly fine.

Your problem is caused by something else. I bet that you're using a very early Mojarra 2.0 version which has some serious bugs in partial state saving. I suggest to upgrade to the latest 2.0 or even 2.1. You can find them all at [Mojarra homepage](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/).

Comment: Ok, thanks! I can't update today... but I'll do it and if it works I'll come back to give you the points for it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You were right about being a Mojarra BUG! But as I can't update right now, I solved by saving the name of the previous page and them returning the name as String instead of returning null. Thanks!